# How to validate PUT parameter in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I use PUT routing:

```
Route::put('offers/{id}/accept', 'OfferController@accept');
```

And controller:

```
public function accept(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        "id" => 'required|integer'
    ]);
}
```

But validation rule does not work for `$id` parameter. How to validate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not particular to put, its particular to any route parameter. This is because route params not included in the `all()` collection.

```
public function accept(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(array_merge(
        [
          'id'=>$id
        ], 
        $request->all()
    ), [
        "id" => 'required|integer'
    ]);
}
```